# Admin on rest HMR example

Tags: admin-on-rest

Does anybody have an good example with HMR (hot module replacement) working with admin-on-rest?
Currently I got errors

`Warning: You cannot change <Router history>`

Comment: HMR should work out of the box ideally. Since the project is bootstrapped with Create-React-App. This must be an unrelated issue.

Comment: https://medium.com/superhighfives/hot-reloading-create-react-app-73297a00dcad